# cannot install anything using yaourt on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, yaourt

If I try to install using `yaourt` I get same error for every package, and it asks me to build package again and again.

```
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libfakeroot.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded
(cannot open shared object file): ignored.
pacman: invalid option -- '7'
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in package().
    Aborting...
```

I have `fakeroot`, `base-devel` packages installed.

Comment: where'd you get `yaourt`?

Comment: @mikeserv I installed it using `pacman`. I hope you are familiar with arch linux

Comment: `yaourt` is not included in any of the standard repos. so where did you get it? have you added the http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch repo to `pacman.conf` or did you get it elsewhere? it looks like your `ld` and `yoaurt` packages are out of sync. which was last updated and when?

Comment: I have installed it by adding repo.archlinux.fr/$arch repo to `pacman.conf`. I did `pacman Syyu` before

Comment: [never do `Syyu`](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=133023) unless you're sure you have to.

Comment: @mikeserv now what?

Comment: well, now you have to track your dependencies - you skipped some most likely. build `pacman`. or `--force` some trouble packages - could be iffy - or get the iso and `pacstrap -r /path/to/your/mounted/root base base-devel --force`. backup `/etc` first if it goes that far.

Comment: @mikeserv I did what you said in your command above, but it didnt solve the problem. I didnt use `-r` option since there is no such option for pacstrap

Comment: oh. that's just `pacman`. apparently you need `pacstrap -cGH /path/to/chroot base base-devel`, or so it appears...

Comment: @mikeserv I used pacstrap without any option, will providing those option and trying again will be better?

Comment: well... it uses the host's package `-c`ache rather than the target's - which is what would happen by default, and wouldn't be very helpful in your case. so possibly. but... ?

Comment: @mikeserv `pacstrap -cGH /path/to/chroot base base-devel` did not work for me again, now what to do?